# Problema al importar matriz compleja Mathematica, ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse

Tags: matrices, importación, wolfram-mathematica

Saludos tengo un problema al importar datos de una matriz 3d compleja dentro de mathematica, la matriz es de dimensión {20,20,20} el comando que ocupo es

```
Q0=ToExpression[Import["Q.bin","Complex128"]]
```

Notar que Q.bin contiene todo el directorio así que he descartado que el error este relacionado con la dirección del fichero, el error que me arroja es:

> ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse 0.0959023 -4.86456*10^-17 I as
>   input.   ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse 0. +0. I as input.
>   ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse 0. +0. I as input.
>   General::stop: Further output of ToExpression::esntx will be
>   suppressed during this calculation.

Sospecho que el problema esta relacionado de alguna forma con al dimensión pero no estoy demasiado familiarizado con mathematica para encontrarlo, estoy continuando el trabajo de otra persona y por ende no me seria fácil cambiar todo el resto del código.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas usar `ToExpression`, sino `ArrayReshape`:

```
Q0 = ArrayReshape[Import["Q.bin", "Complex128"], {20, 20, 20}]
```

Recuerda que `ToExpression` lo que hace es convertir un `String` en una expresión interpretada, y en este caso `Import` ya devuelve una lista de complejos, y lo único que falta es darle las dimensiones correctas, que son las que mencionas. `ArrayReshape` hace exactamente eso, convierte la lista unidimensional a las dimensiones pedidas.

Comment: Sería bueno que edites la respuesta y expliques el motivo por el que necesita cambiar eso o explicar detalladamente en qué afecta ese cambio o si soluciona el problema.